# Apply CSS Animation on overlapping images

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Am trying to achieve this animation on the [CISO website header](https://www.cisco.com/). I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/txvjua3c/) showing what i was able to achieve but something seems off.

```css
img {
  transition: all .3s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: auto;
}

#img2 {}

#img1,
#img3 {
  z-index: 3;
}


/* hover effects */

#img2:hover {
  transform: scaleX(1.08);
  z-index: 8;
}

#img1:hover {
  transform: scaleX(1.08);
  z-index: 8;
}

#img3:hover {
  transform: scaleX(1.08);
  z-index: 8;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="d-flex bd-highlight">
    <div class="flex-fill bd-highlight">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals" alt="" id="img1">
    </div>
    <div class="flex-fill bd-highlight">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature" alt="" id="img2">
    </div>
    <div class="flex-fill bd-highlight">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/arch" alt="" id="img3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Am using bootstrap framework to align the images.

Comment: by "something seems off.' do you mean that the animation isn't triggered as you scroll through the page, but only when you move your cursor over the image? if so, please add that to your question

Comment: I mean when i hover over the images. The middle image seems okay but the ones on the left and right. The effect isn't what i want. As you can check out for the CISCO site, the images (on the left and right) overlap the one in the middle covering almost all of it. Mine don't do so and there seems to be a lag when you hover from one image to another..

Answer (score 0):

Just add this css

```
.flex-fill{
  display:inline-block;
  width:33%;
}
    img:not(:hover) {
  transition: none;
}
```

Comment: @codingmoster still seeing no effect.

Comment: What effect do you mean?